# Filtering a dynamo db table yields Invalid KeyConditionExpression GSI

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table that contains an id and a name, I have a GSI index with the partition key **theName** and the sort column **Last_attended** . I'm trying to query it using a Lambda but I'm not able to return any results. I keep getting errors around the formatting. I'm using the DocumentClient with the query method, it just keep giving me a different error every time I run it.
Not sure what I'm missing here, any help is appreciated.....

!-- data

```
{
  "id": 20919382411,
  "Belt_awarded": "green",
},
{
  "id": 20919382412,
  "Belt_awarded": "yellow",
}
```

!--- code

```
 const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

   const params = {
      TableName : `students`,
      "IndexName": "theName-Last_attended-index",
      KeyConditionExpression: '#id = :id_val',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":id_val": {"N": "20919382411"}, ':v_name': { 'S': 'joe' } }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your `ExpressionAttributeNames` ?

You defined `#id` as expression attribute but you don't declare any `ExpressionAttributeNames`

You are using document client. It should be something like this

```
const params = {
    TableName: 'students',
    IndexName: 'Belt_awarded-index',
    KeyConditionExpression: '#Belt_awarded = :Belt_awarded',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#Belt_awarded': 'Belt_awarded'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':Belt_awarded': 'yellow'
    },
};
```

Comment: Hi @CanSahin, I tried your modification but I get the following:  message: 'Value provided in ExpressionAttributeValues unused in expressions: keys: {:v_name}',
  code: 'ValidationException',

Comment: My Index has a partition key theName (String) & sort key
Last_attended (String) what else do I need to do?

Comment: ohh true no `:v_name` because you dont use it anywhere. Just realized. I updated my answer

Comment: This is part of the index though. I tried to remove it myself and it was returning errors. Since its part of the index, we need to include it right?

Comment: I dont understand. Your index name is either right or wrong. If its correct and if your expressions are correct (valid for your table) then it should work fine. Double check your expressions

Comment: I updated the index and removed the ID from the query. It started to return results. Thanks for the help... I updated your answer to reflect my changes. You were right. I had the index with two columns, one of them had no correlation to the source table.